# Facebook SDK for PHP や Opauth でFacebookからメールアドレスが取得できません。

Tags: php, facebook

Facebook SDK for PHP や Opauth を 使用してFacebookのアカウントでログインする仕組みを作ろうとしていますが、scopeでemailを指定してもメールアドレスが取得できず困っています。

①「developers.facebook.com」でアプリを作成し、「App ID」「App Secret」は取得しています。(v2.4)

②下記URLのFacebookの認証画面で「メールアドレスを受け取る」と書いてあり、OKを押しますが・・・
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=【App ID】&redirect_uri=【App Secret】&scope=email

③返ってきたアクセストークンを使用して下記URLから情報を取得しますが、ユーザー名とIDしか取得できません。
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=【ACCESS_TOKEN】

④Facebook SDK for PHPの設定

```
$config = array(
    'appId' => '【App ID】',
    'secret' => '【App Secret】'
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

if ($facebook->getUser()) {
    try {
        $user = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
    } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        //取得に失敗したら例外をキャッチしてエラーログに出力
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
    }
}

・
・
・

if (isset($user)) {
    //ログイン済みでユーザー情報が取れていれば表示
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($user);
    echo '</pre>';
} else {
//未ログインならログイン URL を取得してリンクを出力
    $params = array('scope' => 'email', 'redirect_uri' => '【URL】');
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Login with Facebook</a>';
}
```

⑤Opauthの設定

```
// opauth.conf.php

・
・
・

        'Strategy' => array(
            // Define strategies and their respective configs here

            'Facebook' => array(
                        'app_id' => '【App ID】',
                        'app_secret' => '【App Secret】',
                        'scope' => array('email')
             ),

        ),
・
・
・
```

以上、的を得た質問になっているかわかりませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ご指摘いただいたので解決方法を記載します。

おそらくFacebookの仕様変更が原因だと思われます。

https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=【ACCESS_TOKEN】
上記ではメールアドレスは取得できませんが、

https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email?access_token=【ACCESS_TOKEN】
とすることでメールアドレスを取得することができました。

具体的には、 Opauth の場合だと、

/lib/Opauth/Strategy/Facebook/FacebookStrategy.phpの

```
$me = $this->serverGet('https://graph.facebook.com/me', array('access_token' => $access_token), null, $headers);
```

を

```
$me = $this->serverGet('https://graph.facebook.com/me', array('fields' => 'id,name,email','access_token' => $access_token), null, $headers);
```

にすることで取得できると思います。